# How can i store images taked with react-native-camera-kit in a laravel server?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i'm using react-native-camera-kit to take photos but how can i store the photos in a backend server on laravel, the actual photo not the uri or the name. Help please.

Comment: Please post a code snippet of what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, it's about react or laravel?

you can use fetch in react to send the request :

```
export function sendImage(file) {
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append("image", file);

  let url = "https://yourapiurl";
  let method = "POST";
  return fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    body: formData,
  })
    .then(function() {
    console.log("ok");
}).catch(function() {
    console.log("error");
});
}
```

and get the sent data in you laravel controller

```
public function SaveImage(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
        ]);
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
        $SavedImage = public_path('images/'). $imageName;

       // do whatever you want with 


        return Response::json(['msg' => 'ok'],200);
    }
```